# How to handle Unseen Test Data in Scikitlearn Randomforest Model python 3

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, data-science

I have a dataset, which contains 14 columns and 111256 rows. Last column contains the ids  and will be use as target column (Y). After using Train,Test split scikitlearn Tree classifier implemented.

> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>
> forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
>
> forest = forest.fit(X, Y)

Results for this prediction is prefect. I can say it should be perfect. Because, this data contains the predicted column. After this I can export the results as well, using pickle dump.
Question is, when I use the unseen test data which contains the predicted column with null values. I get the totally wrong predicted values. (using this command)

> predic= forest.predict(Test_Data)

Any clue how to proceed from here. I tried different techniques but no use. For example , I used to convert all nulls to 0 but results are not what I want. As, in the documentation of the RF that it is a good algorithm for prediction purposes.
If you think I am doing something wrong please let me know. I will be very grateful for this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say `id` are your target column. What are the possible values of `id`?

Comment: these are the numbers like,
  id=[  26, 5,12,34,12,45,  100]

Comment: Do all samples have different ids? If yes, Then I dont think that classifier would work. You are trying to predict a numerical value from other values. This will be best suited for [regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html). Also [standardize your data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)

Comment: No vivek, I have 109 total ids which used repeatedly for 111256 samples.

Comment: You say that the `Test_data` contains the target column with 0 or null values. You should not put target column in that. Just use your other columns (features) for prediction. And also please provide other columns type and some samples.

Comment: It just has no sense to predict a target with the target contained in the training set: the perfect result that you will have is just a projection on that feature (which is the target). But nothing has been learned. Take that column from `X` and use instead a `OneVsAll Classifier` coupled with a `Random Forest Classifier`